# Polars GroupBy, ignore NaNs when calculating mean

Tags: python, python-polars

What is the best way to ignore NaNs when calculating the mean in Polars? As of polars v0.19.19, the default `pl.Expr.mean` does not ignore NaNs.

Example:

```
test_data = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "values": [1, np.nan, 2, 3]
     
     }
)
test_data.group_by("group").agg(pl.col("values").mean())
```

results in

```
group values
"A"    NaN
"B"    2.5
```

Compared to pandas:

```
test_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "values": [1, np.nan, 2, 3]
     
     }
)
test_data.groupby("group").mean()
```

results in

```
group values
"A"    1.0
"B"    2.5
```

The best alternative I can think of is using polars `pl.Expr.map_elements` and `np.nanmean` as such:

```
test_data = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "values": [1, np.nan, 2, 3]
     
     }
)
test_data.group_by("group").agg(
    pl.col("values").map_elements(lambda x: np.nanmean(x.to_numpy()))
)
```

However, the polars API doesn't recommend using it if possible due its lack of speed. Are there faster ways to calculate the mean while ignoring NaNs?

Comment: Can you replace the NaNs with nulls? e.g. with `.fill_nan(None)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TLDR.* You can simply drop the NaNs before computing the mean.

```py
df.group_by("group").agg(pl.col("values").drop_nans().mean())
```

**Output.**

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ values │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ f64    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ A     ┆ 1.0    │
│ B     ┆ 2.5    │
└───────┴────────┘
```

---

**Performance comparison against `pl.Expr.fill_nan(None)`.**

We start by creating an example dataset with 100 million rows and ~20% NaNs in the *values* column.

```py
import random
import string

N_ROWS = 100_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(N_ROWS)],
    "values": [random.random() if random.random() > 0.2 else np.nan for _ in range(N_ROWS)]
})
```

Both methods yield identical results.

```py
df_drop = df.group_by("group", maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col("values").drop_nans().mean())
df_fill = df.group_by("group", maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col("values").fill_nan(None).mean())
assert np.allclose(df_drop.select("values").to_numpy(), df_fill.select("values").to_numpy())
```

Timing both methods yields.

```py
%timeit df.group_by("group").agg(pl.col("values").drop_nans().mean())
# 1.21 s ± 28.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%timeit df.group_by("group").agg(pl.col("values").fill_nan(None).mean())
# 737 ms ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Hence, using `pl.Expr.fill_nan(None)` gives a ~1.6x speed-up. However, unless you are working with dataframes having *hundreds of millions* of rows, the impact is likely negligible.

**Note.** I've noticed that the relationship above reverses with increasing number of groups. In such cases, efficient parallelisation becomes increasingly important.

Comment: **Note.** The result for a group will be `None` if all values for that group are NaN.

Comment: Is it better to drop the nans or to fill the NaNs with nulls like what @jqurious suggested?

Comment: @SamV The results will be identical. I'll also do a quick performance experiment and report back here.

Comment: @SamV I've edited the answer to include a brief performance comparison.